# Mat is not a numerical tuple openCV 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, typeerror

I am relatively new to python and to openCV, I am trying to create a program that grabs input from my Macs' webcam and displays it in a window, and ultimately can process and edit these frames. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as nmp
capture=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    frame = capture.read()
    cv2.imshow("Webcam", frame)
    if (cv2.waitKey(0)):
        break

cv2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

my light near my webcam turns on but then the program stops with the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/spinder/Desktop/WebCam.py", line 7, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("Webcam", frame)
TypeError: mat is not a numerical tuple
```

there are similar questions in here but they do not fix my problem, any advice, fix or workaround would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: change `frame = capture.read()` to  `res, frame = capture.read()` and `cv2.imshow("Webcam", frame)` to `if res: cv2.imshow("Webcam", frame)`

Comment: thanks, eyllanesc, could you post this as an answer so I can accept it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv2.VideoCapture.read):

> Python: cv2.VideoCapture.read([image]) → retval, image

This returns 2 values, the first indicates if the frame is obtained correctly and the second is the frame. So in your case the code should be as follows:

```
import cv2
import numpy as nmp

capture=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    res, frame = capture.read()
    if res:
        cv2.imshow("Webcam", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: also for anyone with similar code, it should be capture.release() or cv2.VideoCapture().release() instead of just cv2.release()

Comment: also this may be off-topic considered it was not the original question but now it is only showing the first frame of my webcam when the program activates, can anyone help?

Comment: @3NiGMa 
you have to pass waitKey () a non-zero value so you have time to get another image.

Comment: thanks, @eyllanesc,  you've been really helpful, +1!